How to catch apollo client errors in next.js error handler
I have a next 14 app with Apollo Client and I want that any error from gql to be handled by a generic error handler that I created, I'm wondering if my approach of throwing error from component is the best way to do it.
Server component
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache, gql } from '@apollo/client'
import { registerApolloClient } from '@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc'

const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(
  () =>
    new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: new HttpLink({ uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_URL, credentials: 'same-origin' }),
    }),
)


export default async function SummariesPage() {
  const data = await getClient().query({ query: gql`ANY_QUERY` })

  if (data.errors) {
    // send error to Sentry
    throw new Error('Error fetching data') // IS THIS THE BEST APPROACH TO DELEGATE ERROR HANDLING TO NEXT?
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center">
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  )
}


and then I have this error handler
'use client'

import { Alert, AlertDescription, AlertTitle } from '@/components/ui/alert'
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import { AlertCircle } from 'lucide-react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Error({ error, reset }: {
  error: Error & { digest?: string }
  reset: () => void
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.error(error)
  }, [error])

  return (
    <Alert variant="destructive" className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
        <AlertCircle className="h-6 w-6 hidden md:block" />
        <div className="text-justify">
          <AlertTitle>Oops! Something went wrong</AlertTitle>
          <AlertDescription>{error.message}</AlertDescription>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span className="text-xs text-gray-500 text-justify">
        Our team has been notified and we are working to fix the problem.
      </span>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => reset()} variant="destructive" className="!p-2 w-full sm:w-auto">
          Try again
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Alert>
  )
}


